# Objective-C "if not equal or" statement not working

Tags: objective-c

I'm relatively new to Objective-C.

I'm trying to construct an `if` statement to check if something is not equal to 'a' nor 'b' and when I add the "or" part, it doesn't seem to work for either statement. If I remove the "or", it works for one or the other.

This code works (for one statement):

```
NSString *source = metaItem.stringValue;
NSString *baddata = @"a";
NSString *baddata2 = @"b";
if (![source isEqualToString:baddata])
{
    if(![source isEqualToString:self.songInfo.text])
    {
        self.songInfo.text = [source stringByAppendingString:@"  "];                
    }
}
```

Equally, if I change `baddata` to `baddata2` it also works correctly. But if I change it to this (to detect either) neither of them are detected:

```
if (![source isEqualToString:baddata] || ![source isEqualToString:baddata2])
```

Is the `if` line incorrect? Do I need to use something like "nor" and if so, what is the syntax?

Comment: logically it's be the correct (using AND operator) `if (![source isEqualToString:baddata] && ![source isEqualToString:baddata2]) { ... }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `baddata` and `baddata2` are different, your condition is always true: any string would be not equal to one or the other, because no string could be equal to two unequal values at once.

You need to change the condition to `&&`:

```
if (![source isEqualToString:baddata] && ![source isEqualToString:baddata2])
```

or use [*De Morgan's Laws*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to combine the middle:

```
if (!([source isEqualToString:baddata] || [source isEqualToString:baddata2]))
```

If you have more than two "baddata" values, consider constructing a hash set from them, and use set containment checks instead of a chain of logical ANDs/ORs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if (![source isEqualToString:baddata] && ![source isEqualToString:baddata2])
```

There is no NOR operator as it is, but you can use OR and then negate the whole condition as this:

```
if (!([source isEqualToString:baddata] || [source isEqualToString:baddata2]))
```

Comment: You've mixed up `self.songInfo.text` and `baddata2`.